# Smart Selection of Training Data for Fine-tuning Language Models in Small Domains

Tags: nlp, dataset, language-model

### Background

I am working to make language models (for example, Stanford's Alpaca model) perform well on a new small domain through fine-tuning on domain-specific dataset $D$.

If the size of $D$ is $N$, I would like to find a subset $n \ll N$ to fine-tune the model due to my limited computation resource: I could only afford to fine-tune the model for 24 GPU hours but fine-tuning on the entire $D$ will take 2400 GPU hours.

### Question

Is there any strategy I could select $n$ smartly so that the model I fine-tuned is likely to perform better than if I choose $n$ in alternative ways? Here are two options I could think of:

- Randomly select $n$ from $N$.
- Measure the quality of each of $N$ in some way and fine-tune the data by selecting those of higher quality ones. I got this idea from curriculum learning ([a survey paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.13166) in 2020).

### Note

This question has been cross-posted from [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/619713/191779).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Data Selection with Importance Resampling (DSIR)](http://arxiv.org/abs/2302.03169), which applies importance resampling with bag-of-words ngrams estimators. This method is specifically meant to select good data for LLM training.

The authors of the method released their [source code](https://github.com/p-lambda/dsir), so you can just use it.

[This Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/sangmichaelxie/status/1623397365443960832) is a good summary.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! This is super relevant!